# Azure.Identity or Azure.Services.AppAuthentication?

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

Looks like there are two competing libraries for token authentication in Azure:

- [Azure.Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity)
- [Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/mgmtcommon/AppAuthentication)

How can I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Azure.Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity) library uses MSAL and [Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/mgmtcommon/AppAuthentication) library uses ADAL.

MSAL provides multiple benefits over ADAL including incremental consent, richer single sign-on experiences, support for personal Microsoft accounts, use of standards-based protocols, and so on.

So, We recommend using [Azure.Identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity) library since it uses MSAL.